# Loading another controller's view using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to load another controller's view using MVC. I do it using something ike  return View(~/view/Controller/action);

Now this is a stringly typed view and I am using aspx pages to do that. When it loads, it says that Model is Null. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you mean, ASPX pages ? You want to link to a an MVC view from a standard ASP.Net page ?

Comment: No, I mean it's not Razor the view is .aspx extension not cshtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [this overload of View()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310.aspx). The version you're calling doesn't pass in the Model, resulting in and exception.

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TestCase.Models.tblTask', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestCase.Models.tblTask]'.

Comment: Your view is expecting a list but you are passing in an object that isn't a list

Comment: My code is like this: TestCase.Models.tblTask TaskObj = new Models.tblTask();
           

return View("~view/task/index",TaskObj);

Comment: Guys, problem is resolved. I had to pass LINQ query result which is basically a dictionary for that.